# Understanding simple count logic in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, count

I have a very basic question which I cannot answer myself but shouldn't take much of your time.

The following query works, it lists all the `exhibition_category_id` and counts the total of objects that are assigned to each category.

My question is: Why does it do it? I don't understand the query. It says `count(*)` - why doesn't it give me the total of different exhibition_category_id's (79), but instead counts, how many objects are assigned to each category?

Here is the query in question, as well as a screen shot from the actual output:

```
SELECT eb.exhibition_category_id, count(*) AS total 
FROM exhibition_brand eb 
GROUP BY eb.exhibition_category_id
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6deMv.png

Hope its understandable what I am asking for, eager to improve my post based on feedback.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your query is a basic aggregation query:

```
SELECT eb.exhibition_category_id, count(*) AS total
FROM exhibition_brand eb
GROUP BY eb.exhibition_category_id;
```

The `GROUP BY` specifies that the result set will contain one row for each value of `eb.exhibition_category_id`.  The result set consists of two columns, one is the value that defines the row.  The other is a count of the number of rows in each group.  That is what `COUNT(*)` does.

If you wanted the total count of different `eb.exhibition_category_id`, then you want *one* row and `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
select count(distinct eb.exhibition_category_id)
from exhibition_brand eb;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, it really helped me understand

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` function groups the `COUNT()` by `eb.exhibition_category_id`, so the query groups the records by `eb.exhibition_category_id`, then counts the corresponding records.